Right side of the equation is a denominator
Below is my overleaf latex code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 \frac{\partial \log L(\theta)} {\partial\theta_k} 
 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_i \frac{\partial} {\partial \theta_k } \left ( (I_1\theta_1 +\dots+ I_{K-1}\theta_{K-1}+ \beta^\prime W_i )  - \log{\sum_{j=1}^{n}
Y_{ij}(X_i)\exp \left( \sum_{k=1}^{K-1} \theta_{jk} I_{jk} + \beta^\prime W_j  \right)} \right)
\end{equation*}


\end{document}



the RHS with the equal to sign appears in the denominator of the partial derivative. What is the issue with my code?

Welcome. // Please add the 4 or so missing lines to make your code compile. Thank you

The equation looks correct, but maybe too long to fit in a line. Can you show your output? Also, do you get some error somewhere in your real document, that you ignore?


What is the issue with my code?

The OP has failed to load the amsmath package (which provides the equation* environment). The OP has also ignored any number of subsequent error messages. In fairness, it's worth reminding oneself that Overleaf makes it far too easy to ignore error messages.
I would also use \biggl and \biggr instead of \left and \right. And one should probably change log{...} to \log\biggl\{ ... \biggr\}.

\documentclass{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\partial \log L(\theta)} {\partial\theta_k} 
  = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_i \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_k} \biggl( 
  (I_1\theta_1 +\dots+ I_{K-1}\theta_{K-1}+ \beta' W_i )  
  - \log\biggl\{ \sum_{j=1}^{n} Y_{ij}(X_i)
  \exp \biggl(\, \sum_{k=1}^{K-1} \theta_{jk} I_{jk} + \beta' W_j  
  \biggr) \biggr\} \biggr)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


Out of curiosity: why \biggl is preferred over \left?

@SubhajitPaul - Because \left and \right would produce parentheses that are too tall relative to what's typographically optimal for the equation at hand. Do try it out yourself: In the code above, change all three instances of \biggl to \left and all three instances of \biggr to \right, recompile the test document, and assess what's happened to the tall round parentheses and curly braces.
